# Can I receive more bytes in one transfer from this c# to android device?

Tags: c#, android, json, bluetooth

I'm trying to transfer a long string (2286 bytes) over Bluetooth. I've a bit of an issue about receiving a long json string over the bluetooth.. Well, not an issue, because it is receiving it, but in the manner it is receiving it. I was wondering if it was possible to receive more bytes in one transfer or if it's just a limitation.

OK, so on the c# side.. Here's the server loop..

```
 _screenWriterCallBT("Bluetooth Server started, waiting for clients..");
        BluetoothListener blueListener = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
        blueListener.Start();
        BluetoothClient conn = blueListener.AcceptBluetoothClient();
        _screenWriterCallBT("Bluetooth Client has connected");

        Stream mStream = conn.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] recieved = new byte[1024];
                mStream.Read(recieved, 0, recieved.Length);
                string content = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieved);
                _screenWriterCallBT("Recieved: " + content + "via bluetooth");

                ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson();
                JsonReturn = parseJson.InitialParsing(content); //parse message

                byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonReturn);
                mStream.Write(sent, 0, sent.Length);
                _screenWriterCallBT("Test" + sent.Length);
                string messageSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sent);
                _screenWriterCallBT("sent via Bluetooth: " + messageSent);
            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                _screenWriterCallBT("Bluetooth Client has disconnected. Exception:" + exception + "\n");
            }
        }
```

It seems to work.

```
_screenWriterCallBT("Test" + sent.Length); // says 2286 bytes on the long string i'm trying to send.
```

On the Android side I have a server listening and sending too:

```
 public void run() {
    byte[] buffer; 
    int bytes;

    while (true) {
        try {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            // Read from the InputStream
            bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            System.out.println(bytes);

            if(bytes != 0)
                listener.messageReceivedFromServer(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

It works, and receives the bytes, but it receives them in an odd way.

```
System.out.println(bytes); prints 1010, 1010, 266
```

So, basically i'm getting a truncated json string every time and I can't turn that into a JSON object.  I had an idea of when a message was received, it writes it to a temporary string, and it tests if it is a valid json object then carries on until its valid. Anyway, I thought i'd come check if any Stack overflow guru's could shine any light on if i'm doing something wrong or can change something?

Cheers
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read until all data is received, you're only reading from the stream once, thus end up with part of the data. You're partially doing this in the `while(true)` loops, but you don't know when you have a complete data transfer like you've found out.

From the c# side here's an illustration of what is required:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while(mStream.DataAvailable())
{
    byte[] received = new byte[1024];
    mStream.Read(received, 0, received.Length);
    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received));
}
var receivedString = sb.ToString();
_screenWriterCallBT("Received: " + receivedString + "via bluetooth");

ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson();
JsonReturn = parseJson.InitialParsing(receivedString); //parse message
```

Just do the same in the android side.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll have a go now.

Comment: Works, thanks again. Wasn't aware of this DataAvailable method. For anyone who may come across this in the future (probably wont but anyway..) in Android use 'yourInputStream.available()' to return the amount of bytes that are ready to be read. Ben

Comment: No problem - most of these socket api implementations will offer some sort of "available" type method/property for this scenario.